# MacOS 12 — How to set a default DNS server for all user accounts

Tags: dns, accounts

The primary account I use on my Mac is an admin account, when I go online it connects to a DNS server from a 3rd party provider. I'd like this to be applied to any other account (present or future) on the computer.

Currently the other account is the guest account (it gets rest every time you log out of it). When opening the guest account I'd like it to automatically use the same DNS server as the admin. Is there a way for me configure this from the admin account?

Using system preferences, the only agency you have over the guest account is limiting its access to adult content, so I'm hoping this can be done using a terminal command.

I don't need this action to be reversible or easy to undo.
Ideally this would work for any other accounts that are added to the computer.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Unless there's something unusual about your setup, the DNS server is part of the network settings (configured in System Preferences -> Network pane), which are system-wide (i.e. they apply to all users).

Comment: Yeah, that is odd. You could alternatively just set it in the router & hand it out with DHCP

Comment: Thanks @GordonDavisson @Tetsuji 
On the admin account I used this terminal command to set my DNS

`sudo networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xx`

This means that  if I go into system preferences/network/wifi/DNS it doesn't show me that DNS server I set in the terminal.

I'd like the one I set in terminal to be default for the computer on all accounts, present and future. My goal is that no matter which Wifi network I connect to and no matter which user account I connect with, I want to to be as hard as possible for the DNS server to be changed, even by myself.